# How to do query in EF Core / Dotnet Core without having it resorting to a join

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables:

```
// pseudo code:

class User {
  int UserID; // primary key
  string name;
  IEnumerable<Checklist> Checklists;
}

class Checklist {
  int ChecklistID; // primary key
  String name;
}
```

And when I do the following LINQ query:

```
        var result = from checklist in _context.Users
            where checklist.UserID == id 
            select checklist.Checklists;
```

It always resorts to 2 queries, one for the UserID, and then a Select + JOIN:

```
Select .... from Users where ..UserID=@__ID
 .......
Select ... from Checklists C
INNER JOIN ( Select ... from User 
     where 
     UserID = @__id_0
     .....
) as T on C.UserID = T.UserID;
```

The thing is that I already have the ID of the user, so I'd rather make EF do a simple query like this:

```
Select ... from Checklists where UserID = 1;
```

instead of querying for the User with it's ID, and then use that UserID in a new query for Checklist where UserID = that ID

Comment: So don't you have a `_context.CheckLists` ? Why not?

Comment: I do, but I don't have the UserID available as a _context.Checklists.Where(p=>p.UserID)  would work..

Comment: And why don't you have the User and UserId mapped in the CheckList? It's a broken master/detail in EF terms.

Comment: I'll just add UserID then. I just thought that there was a trick to be able to reference the "UserID" attribute because it does exist in the DB.

Thanks for your input. Why don't you say propose an answer saying: "Just add UserID to the Checklist class and then do a _context.Checklist.Where(p => p.UserID == id)" and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I thought that EF would make the UserID available some way, instead of me specifying it in the class itself.

Thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation properties are the mainstay of EF. So your details class should expose its foreign key properties. There is no point in omitting them.

```
class Checklist {
  int ChecklistID; // primary key

  int UserId { get; set; }  // Foreign Key, the std naming patterns will match these
  User User { get; set; }

  String name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EF Core is much flexible than EF6 in that regard. Additionally to explicitly defined properties it also allows you to use [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) inside LINQ query through [`EF.Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF.Property%60%601)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method:

> Addresses a given property on an entity instance. This is useful when you want to reference a shadow state property in a LINQ query.

So with your original model you could use:

```
var result = from checklist in _context.Checklists
             where EF.Property(checklist, "UserId") == id;
```

Of course you can always add explicit navigation and/or FK property in the model, but it's good to have this option in case you don't want to do that (neither navigation nor FK property is mandatory).